# File not found: HsAddin

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperion, smartview, vba

Recently I received macro excel file with Smart View. It was working all fine.

Today I added small piece of code - 5 lines to set formula in a small range of cells and then to do paste special values. That piece of code is correct, tested. Code is added on Workbook_Open, inside already present code.

But what happened, now when i open the file i get error:

> "File not found: HsAddin file".

I checked for answers:

> - to check it in options->addins->disabled items

But there are no disabled items

> - to edit in regedit, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Resiliency,

But there is no Resiliency...

I am running Windows 8, 64-bit operating system, Excel 2013.

Can anyone suggest how to check what has happened to the add-in?

Comment: When you goto Options->Addins - what exactly is there?

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for your time. On the end, i downloaded SmartView, installed and added it in Excel via options-addins and it works now.

Thing is that i didn't have SmartView installed earlier and there were no issues. Now it works fine. 

Only one thing, i see sometimes when opening Excel file it says it is opening HsTbar.xla. Is it because SmartView addin is activated?